# How to select anchor with active=true attribute, add a class and if user selects other anchor, give that class to the new anchor.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to add the class "Selected" with Jquery to an anchor that the only way to catch it is by its attribute "active=true". Then when the user selects other anchor that new anchor will be set as "active=true" and that has to be the new  class "Selected" and the other one not.

The idea is that the selected anchor must be distinguished. The class "Selected could be just ".selected {color:red;}".

```
        When the user selects 1
<span class="paginate_numbers">
    <a active="true" class="paginate_button paginate_number selected">1</a>
    <a class="paginate_button paginate_number">2</a>
    <a class="paginate_button paginate_number">3</a>
    <a class="paginate_button paginate_number">4</a>
    <a class="paginate_button paginate_number">5</a>
</span>

When the user selects 2
<span class="paginate_numbers">
    <a class="paginate_button paginate_number">1</a>
    <a active="true" class="paginate_button paginate_number selected">2</a>
    <a class="paginate_button paginate_number">3</a>
    <a class="paginate_button paginate_number">4</a>
    <a class="paginate_button paginate_number">5</a>
</span>

.selected {color:red;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such attribute as `active`. And, it seems that your use of the `Selected` class and the `active` attribute is redundant since one just signifies the other.

Why not just create a CSS rule for **[`a:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus)** anchors?

```css
a { text-decoration:none; }

/* When an anchor gets the focus, style it. */
a:focus {color:red; background-color:#ff0; }
```

```html
<span class="paginate_numbers">
    <a href="#" class="paginate_button paginate_number">1</a>
    <a href="#" class="paginate_button paginate_number">2</a>
    <a href="#" class="paginate_button paginate_number">3</a>
    <a href="#" class="paginate_button paginate_number">4</a>
    <a href="#" class="paginate_button paginate_number">5</a>
</span>
```

But, if you must dynamically add/remove classes, you can do so without getting attributes involved:

```js
// Get all the appropriate links into a set
var $paginationLiks = $(".paginate_numbers a");

// Set up a click event handler for each link
$paginationLiks.on("click", function(){
  $paginationLiks.removeClass("active"); // Remove the class from all links
  $(this).addClass("active");            // Add class to clicked link
});
```

```css
a { text-decoration:none; }

/* This class is applied to the clicked link */
.active {color:red; background-color:#ff0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="paginate_numbers">
    <a href="#" class="paginate_button paginate_number">1</a>
    <a href="#" class="paginate_button paginate_number">2</a>
    <a href="#" class="paginate_button paginate_number">3</a>
    <a href="#" class="paginate_button paginate_number">4</a>
    <a href="#" class="paginate_button paginate_number">5</a>
</span>
```